# Why, intuitively, we need to pass to the conformal compactification to study the conformal group?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics, conformal-geometry

In the book "A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory" by M. Schottenloher, the author says in in Section 2.1:

> To study the collection of all conformal transformations on an open connected subset $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{p,q}$, $p+q\geq 2$, a conformal compactification $N^{p,q}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ is introduced, in such a way that the conformal transformations $M\to \mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ become everywhere defined and bijective maps $N^{p,q}\to N^{p,q}$. Consequently, we search for a "minimal" compactification $N^{p,q}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ with a natural semi-Riemannian metric, such that every conformal transformation $\varphi : M\to \mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ has a continuation to $N^{p,q}$ as a conformal diffeomorphism $\hat{\varphi}:N^{p,q}\to N^{p,q}$.

Now I would like to understand intuitively why is this necessary. What is the motivation to pass to a conformal compactification?

I mean, can't one simply focus on conformal diffeomorphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^{p,q}\to \mathbb{R}^{p,q}$? What is the obstruction for doing this?

Why introduce a conformal compactification here? What is the motivation and how can we understand such need intuitively?

Comment: The yellow box says the following: Every local conformal map with domain some open subset of $\Bbb R^{p,q}$ extends to a global conformal map with domain and codomain $N^{p,q}$. That seems to be the main motivation, namely that all the maps you are interested in are globally defined (in particular Killing fields now have global flows).

Comment: Think of this as a smartphone: it is not necessary but it is convenient.